# Auto mapper does not work.

Tags: c#, automapper

I've used [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) in my method but doesn't work.
Please help me to correct it.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TViewModel> FindAllByCriteria(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate   = null, params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<TModel> items = RepositoryContainer<TRepository>().FindAll();
        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
            {
                items = items.Include(includeProperty);
            }
        }
        var destination_VMList = new List<TViewModel>();
        var source_tModelList = new List<TModel>();
        source_tModelList = predicate != null ? items.Where(predicate).ToList() : items.ToList();

        Mapper.Map(source_tModelList, destination_VMList); // Error happened!

        return destination_VMList;
    }
```

***Error message:***

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Tag -> TagViewModel
Jahan.Blog.Model.Tag -> Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.TagViewModel

Destination path:
List`1[0]

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tag_F1F5C39705DF9507B542CCC1A519D0757945F8E00B19F4F20C89F81DF8358563
```

Comment: Can you show the AutoMapper profile you created for this mapping?

Comment: I'm new in using Auto Mapper. Can you help me about AutoMapper profile? I didn't write any AutoMapper profile for it.

Comment: I'd say [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/15/automapper-profiles.aspx) is a good resource. Basically you create a class that extends Profile, where you create your mappings, declare custom types and add your funky logic if the properties do not fit 1:1.

Comment: You know if you just add `using Automapper.QueryableExtensions;` to the top of your file you could simplify your program to

`FindAllByCriteria(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> predicate = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TModel> items = RepositoryContainer<TRepository>().FindAll();
        if(predicate != null) { items = items.Where(predicate); }
        return items.Project().To<TViewModel>().ToList();
    }`. It is usually preferable to do `Project().To<T>()` over `Mapper.Map` as it only pulls objects from the server that are needed to perform the mapping, it also removes the need for includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first configure the map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Tag , TagViewModel>();
```

Then you can map like this:

```
var destination_VMList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TModel>, IEnumerable<TViewModel>>(source_tModelList);
```